# Powershell script to retry move-item until success is not working

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following loop to sleep 5 seconds if the attempt to rename the file fails, however, when the event log reports failure ($? is false) it isn't retrying, it just moves on to the next block of code:

```
DO
{
    Move-Item -Path $old_log_name -Destination $new_log_name
    if($?){
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source my_application -EventId 4 -Message "Successfully moved $old_log_name to $new_log_name"
    }
    else{
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source my_application -EventId 4 -Message "Failed to move $old_log_name to $new_log_name : $LastExitCode sleeping 5 secconds"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
} Until ($?)
```

Am I missing something here???  Also on the same topic, $LastExitCode is showing up as blank.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you're trying to do is the following:

1. Try to move the item and set a new name, the names are stored in the variables $old_log_name and $new_log_name.
2. If it fails to rename the item, it should write a fail message to the EventLog and stay in the loop until the item has been moved and renamed.
3. If it succeeds with moving and renaming the item, it should write a success message to the EventLog.

If the above is the case, you can easily achieve this by using a -not (!()) statement in correlation with the Do/Until-loop.

```
$old_log_name = 'C:\temp\test.txt'
$new_log_name = 'C:\temp\temp.txt'

Do {
    if (!(Move-Item -Path $old_log_name -Destination $new_log_name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source my_application -EventId 4 -Message "Failed to move $old_log_name to $new_log_name : sleeping 5 secconds"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}
        Until ((Test-Path $new_log_name) -eq $true) 
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source my_application -EventId 4 -Message "Successfully moved $old_log_name to $new_log_name"
```

The above script will try to move and rename the item until the statement in the until-loop becomes $true. In other words, when the "Test-Path" returns a $true value the loop will have been completed.

The reason as to why: $LastExitCode doesn't work is because it only works with Win32 applications and not with PowerShell commands. A better solution for that in this case would be to add a $true or $false statement to a variable if the statement is $true or $false and then append an errorcode.

Comment: Thanks, I think your understanding is spot on.  Will test this out and see how it works.